# Do you ever need DLC to get the Platinum trophy for a game?

Tags: achievements, ps3

The description of the Platinum trophy for each PS3 game can vary (as with any trophy description). When you're looking at a trophy list and there are trophies for DLC sometimes it is not clear whether the DLC trophies are required to get the Platinum trophy. For example, the Bioshock Platinum trophy description reads "Collected all other Bioshock trophies" which is not clear on whether that includes the DLC trophies.

**Are there any games where DLC trophies are required to be able to get the Platinum trophy?**

Comment: +1 because i don't know anything about this thing but i'm interested in too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  When designing trophy sets for PS3 games, one of the requirements is that all of the base trophies must be earnable without DLC.  Sony will not let developers publish games that do not meet this (and many more) requirements.

Comment: Are those requirements listed publicly anywhere, or just gleaned from leaks from developers? I'd be interested to read them. :)   I remember reading that Heavy Rain had to get special permission from Sony to delay the "you got a trophy" popup until the end of the chapter, because the dev felt it broke the immersion for it to pop up during gameplay.

Answer (score 5):

The updated answer is "It depends if you consider network passes as DLC".

Many recent PS3 games lock their online content behind a "network pass", a small piece of DLC you need to download from the PlayStation Store but can be redeemed for free by using a one-time code included with new copies of the game. If you bought a used game but want to use the online features, you'll need to buy the code separately (usually for around $10).

If the platinum requirements for these games include online trophies, you'll need that piece of DLC, not all games that have a network pass require online play for platinum, though. Examples of games which require a network pass to platinum are Ratchet & Clank All 4 One and Uncharted 3. Sites like PS3Trophies.org usually list if a game's platinum requires an online pass.

One exception worth mentioning: EyePet has a trophy for downloading content off the store, that content could be free content, but if you don't have access to the store through the game (for example if the store is unavailable in your region or the game's region is different than your account's region), you cannot platinum the game.

Comment: I'm going to add to that network qualifier, in the case of a game like Uncharted 2 if for some reason the multi-player match-up server gets pulled, you would no longer be able to get Platinum as it requires you to have completed two on-line matches.

Answer (score 3):

Another edge case where your definition of "DLC" may change the answer: episodic games like Walking Dead or Life Is Strange. In these games, you have to play through all episodes of the season to get platinum. If you consider episodes 2-5 to be DLC for episode 1, then this would be another case where you need DLC.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't, but without dlc, your percentage will be lower. Like you could only have 80% of trophies but still get platinum.

For example, I had bioshock 2, and about 60% of trophies. I hadn't played it online yet, and I hadn't downloaded patches. And when I finished single player,I wanted to test it online, so I had to download all the patches, and it downloaded only dlc trophies, and my percentage lowered to 45%.

Comment: yes, percentage calculation might vary if new trophies are added but you can still have a platinum and not be at 100% completion.